# Python if-else mess

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

Is there a cleaner way to create `msg`? For each event (Ping, Pull request, Issue, Issue comment, Repo, Create, Delete, Pull requset review, Push, Commit comment) is there an if clause that checks the event and creates a message according to it's action.

```
    data = request.json
    event = request.headers['X-Github-Event']
    msg = ""

    ...

   # Pull request
   elif event == "pull_request":
       if data['action'] == "opened":
           msg = PullRequest(data).opened()
       elif data['action'] == "closed":
           msg = PullRequest(data).closed()
       elif data['action'] == "assigned":
           msg = PullRequest(data).assigned()

   # Issue
   elif event == "issues":
        if data['action'] == "opened":
            msg = Issue(data).opened()
        elif data['action'] == "reopened":
            msg = Issue(data).reopened()
        elif data['action'] == "closed":
            msg = Issue(data).closed()
        elif data['action'] == "labeled":
            msg = Issue(data).labeled()
        elif data['action'] == "assigned":
            msg = Issue(data).assigned()
    ...
```

Comment: `getattr(Issue(data), data['action'])()` and similar for `PullRequest`. If you have an `else` clause for an unknown action, wrap it in a try-except block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about doing so dynamically, e.g.

```
getattr(PullRequest(data), data['action'], lambda:None)()
```

In summary

```
elif event == "pull_request":
    getattr(PullRequest(data), data['action'], lambda:None)()
elif event == "issues":
    getattr(Issue(data), data['action'], lambda:None)()
```

Where the idea behind `lambda:None` is that it stands for a default callable if `data['action']` is actually not a method of `PullRequest(data)` or `Issue(data)`.

---

Or if you do not like `if-else` statements, something like

```
callables = {
    "pull_request":PullRequest,
    "issues":Issue,
}

getattr(callables[event](data), data['action'], lambda:None)()
```

Comment: The wrappers aren't necessary; e.g., `lambda d: PullRequest(d)` is the same as `PullRequest` by itself.

Comment: @chepner. I am not wrapping it. I simply do not want to instantiate PullRequest if not needed. Do you see my point ?

Comment: Functions and types are first class objects; simply referencing one doesn't call it.

Comment: Good to know. Thx @chepner. (*Which thus appears to be a difference with python27*, admitedly, this question is python-3.x related).

Comment: No, this has been true since Python 1.x. (I don't recall if Python 0.x was a thing.)

Comment: ? `def yo():print "yo"` and `print {'a':yo(),'b':yo()}` prints `"yo"` twice, doesn't it ? @chepner

Comment: I'm not taking about *calling* the function in the dictionary, but using the function itself *as* the value: `{ "pull_request": PullRequest, "issues": Issue}`, not `{"pull_request": PullRequest(), "issues": Issue()}`.

Comment: @chepner. Yes you are right !!! 01h45 here. I was seeing, say, `PullRequest()()` (in the case `__call__` is a method involved)  not `PullRequest()`. But, instantiation isn't costly ?

Comment: It's relatively costly (only an issue if you are making a lot of calls), but it's visually cluttered to define unnecessary functions. Using callables as first-class values is a common idiom in Python.

Comment: Ok ok. Thx @chepner.

Comment: I just re-read everything, and I really wonder where my mind was at that time.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the conditionals with a `dict`s that map strings to the appropriate objects. (This is a generalization of what Kanak proposes, in the strings you care examining don't need to match the names of your methods.)

```
functions = {
    "pull_requests": {
        "opened" : methodcaller("opened"),
        "closed" : methodcaller("closed"),
        "assigned" : methodcaller("assigned")
    },
    "issues": {
        "opened" : methodcaller("opened"),
        "reopened" : methodcaller("reopened"),
        "closed" : methodcaller("closed"),
        "assigned" : methodcaller("assigned"),
        "labeled": methodcaller("labeled")
    }   
}

classes = {
    "pull_requests": PullRequest,
    "issues": Issue
}

obj = classes[event]
msg = functions[event][data['action']](obj)
```

Comment: You could put references to unbound methods in the `functions` dictionaries, rather than using `methodcaller` with string arguments. E.g. `functions = { "pull_requests": { "opened" : PullRequest.opened, ...}, ...}`.

Comment: @Blckknght That would expand the number of places where we refer to the class, and need to make changes should we ever decide to use a different class. Using `methodcaller` more directly reflects that we are invoking a method on a particular instance, rather than calling a specific class's method.